# Sharepoint 2007 workflow WhileActivity

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to build worflow (on Sharepoint 2007 ) which contains a WhileActivity ,The workflow works successfully without WhileActivity ,When i added WhileActivity to workflow designer , the workflow stops after InitializeComponent() method.

Is There any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a wrokaround this issue by swicth condition from declarative to code.